# WooCommerce API - Is there a way to _delete_ meta values?

Tags: api, metadata

Is there a way to *delete* meta values through the WooCommerce API?  We have wound up with duplicate meta values and we can't find a way to remove them.

Answer (score 4):

You can send update with metadata key and **without** value to unset metadata.

So let's assume you want to update order metadata. You can do it by sending PUT request for your order:

```
PUT https://{yoursite.com}/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/{id}
Body: 
{
   "meta_data":[
      {
         "key":"{your_meta_key}",
         "value":"{your_meta_value}"
      }
   ]
}
```

Then if you want to remove this meta key you can send:

```
PUT https://{yoursite.com}/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/{id}
Body: 
{
   "meta_data":[
      {
         "key":"{your_meta_key}"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Mateusz, thanks.  If you post key with no value and then you retrieve it later, will it not be in the list at all or will it still be listed with a blank value?  Our problem is that someone posted the same key value twice with different values and now we're stuck with two entries.  Ideally, we want one of them completely gone.

Comment: If you put it like in the second example it will be deleted completely. If you put it with empty value (so for example: `"value":""` it will remain with blank value. I didn't test how it behave when there are two meta values with the same key. Probably both will be deleted, but I'm not 100% sure. In this case I would first get values for that key, then delete this meta, and then re-add value only once.